# Where did 125 of my reputation go?

Tags: support, reputation

It seems I have lost 125 reputation on Stack Overflow since yesterday. Of course this has happened before when a user/question gets removed. However this has always been reflected in the reputation tab of my profile. This time I see no evidence what happened for me to lose my reputation. Is there another reason a user may lose reputation? What can I do to figure out what happened?

Comment: Why do you ask this here and not on meta.stackoverflow.com? But before you do that, there a similar questions already, so please check them first.

Comment: Why do I ask here: because whatever happened I believe it will be shared among all SE sites, I doubt it is specific for stackoverflow. Looking at similar questions: I did but what I found as I point out in my question is that deleting user/question may cause this

Comment: Did you check the "recently deleted answers/questions" information for your account? Maybe a high flying answer was deleted together with the corresponding question. You wouldnt see that anywhere: just on the day you collected that reputation, the gains no longer show up.

Comment: There are currently no notifications for rep changes. Hopefully within few days it will be back, and you'll see why you lost the reputation.

Comment: presumably, this is the [rep recalc for this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/); sometimes, rep drifts for a range of reasons - a recalc (which applied to everyone) merely normalizes reality

Comment: @MarcGravell but isn't there a daily job that performs full recalc anyway?

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard not my speciality area, to be honest

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard so you say this is a recent change that caused it? Because definitely before I was able to see the reason

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica I am not sure how to access this information. I took a look at questions/answers ordered by activity also all actions on my posts. It has happened to me before that my answer gets deleted together with the question but this has always been reported in the reputation tab

Comment: There are currently a lot of users resigning and deleting their accounts, normally this leads to a revocation of reputation, too.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica but I am certain the behavior was different a few weeks ago. I got a log even for the exact same case

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica here is one example: https://pasteboard.co/IGD8Za9.png and the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776436/prove-that-this-is-of-ologn/23777098#23777098

Comment: Looks like a side-effect of the big rep recalculation—or is it in fact a bug?

Comment: @jknappen-ReinstateMonica so far I believe the question linked as duplicate explains the behavior. We will see with time

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yesterday we had a global reputation recalculation in order to [retroactively award +10 for asking](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). We anticipated a small number of people might *lose* reputation if their reputation hadn't been recalculated recently. So it's reasonable to assume that is the case here.

However, I looked at your user history and discovered this notation:

```
Global Recalc: question upvote value change old rep = 58498, new rep = 59373
```

Clearly you *gained* 875 yesterday, so I wondered how you might have thought you'd lost 125. Then I noticed `58373 - 58498 = -125`. Is it possible you had mis-remembered the thousands place on your previous reputation?

Comment: You are right of course :) silly me. Naturally I never get that much reputation in one day so usually I don't keep track of the thousands. Before asking this question I was not aware of the recalc

Comment: @izomorphiusSupportMonica: Glad to have cleared it up!